# All Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My server gives me following log error

> [Sat Jan 26 09:56:39.326027 2019] [core:error] [pid 24713] [client xxxxx] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

My htaccess is

```html
ServerSignature Off
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^c/(.+) category.php?path=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^p/.+\.([0-9]+)\.htm products.php?productId=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^News/([0-9]*)-[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]* news.php?news=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^coupons/?$ coupons_category.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^coupons/([0-9]*)/[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.'"]* coupons.php?catId=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^cashbacks/?$ cashbacks.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^logo/[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*-([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_]*)-([0-9]*)x([0-9]*).jpg thumbnail.php?f=upload/merchant/$1.jpg&w=$2&h=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^logo/[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*-([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_]*).jpg rf.php?f=upload/merchant/$1.jpg [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ contactus.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us$ aboutus.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^advertising$ advertising.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^terms-of-use$ termsofuse.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^recent-searches$ recent_searches.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^link-to-us$ linktous.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchants$ merchants.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^partnership$ partnership.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy$ privacy_policy.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap$ sitemap.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^faqs$ faq.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^news$ news.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^featured-products$ featured_products.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^popular-products$ popular_products.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchant/merchant_welcome.htm merchant/merchant_welcome.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchant/merchant_login.htm merchant/merchant_login.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchant/merchant_logout.htm merchant/merchant_logout.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchant/merchant_register.htm merchant/merchant_register.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\_]*)/Profile/? merchant_detail.php?fn=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\_]*)/Reviews/? user_rating.php?fn=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\_]*)/Products/? search_products.php?mpp=1&merFN=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Search/(.*) search_products.php?searchText=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^brands.htm brands.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^brand/([a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*) search_products.php?manuText=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9&\_\-\+'"]+)/brand/([a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*) category.php?categoryFn=$1&manuText=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.+\.([0-9]+)/brand/([a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*) category.php?categoryId=$1&manuText=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^license[a-z0-9\-]*.lic 404.shtml
RewriteRule ^license[a-z0-9\-]*.txt 404.shtml
RewriteRule ^images/([a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)x([0-9]*).jpg product-thumb.php?pf=$1&p=$2&w=$3&h=$4 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^image/thumb-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*).jpg product-thumb.php?p=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^image/large-([0-9]*).jpg product-image.php?p=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^brand-image/thumb-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*).jpg rf.php?f=upload/brand/$1.jpg&w=$2&h=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^category_taxonomy.htm category_taxonomy.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_profile.htm member_profile.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_login.htm member_login.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_register.htm member_register.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_welcome.htm member_welcome.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_verify_email.htm member_verify_email.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_change_pwd.htm member_change_pwd.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_profile.htm member_profile.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_product_rating.htm member_product_rating.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_user_rating.htm member_user_rating.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_logout.htm member_logout.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_forgot_pwd_form.htm member_forgot_pwd_form.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_productlist_add.htm member_productlist_add.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^all-stores.htm all-stores.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchant_ranking.htm merchant_ranking.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchant_detail.htm merchant_detail.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^category.htm category.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^category_listing.htm category_listing.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^micro_category.htm micro_category.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sub_category.htm sub_category.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^product_rating.htm product_rating.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^products_price_alert.htm products_price_alert.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^search_products.htm search_products.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^search.htm search.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^products.htm products.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^compare_products.htm compare_products.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.htm index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^currency.htm currency.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^language.htm language.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^redirect.htm redirect.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^featured_offers.htm featured_offers.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^user_rating.htm user_rating.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^price_alert_subscribe.htm price_alert_subscribe.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^email_friend.htm email_friend.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^search_advanced.htm search_advanced.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_productlist_public.htm member_productlist_public.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^coupons_category.htm coupons_category.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^cookie-policy.htm cookie-policy.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^member_store_cart_orders.htm member_store_cart_orders.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchant_store_cart_add.htm merchant_store_cart_add.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchant_store_cart_bank_payment.htm merchant_store_cart_bank_payment.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchant_store_cart_checkout.htm merchant_store_cart_checkout.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchant_store_cart_process.htm merchant_store_cart_process.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^merchant_store_cart_view.htm merchant_store_cart_view.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.+\.([0-9]+)/.+\.ebay-([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)\.htm products_ebay.php?apiType=$2&categoryId=$1&productId=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.+\.([0-9]+)/.+\.review-([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)\.htm product_rating.php?apiType=$2&categoryId=$1&productId=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.+\.([0-9]+)/.+\.discussion-([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)\.htm products_discussion.php?apiType=$2&categoryId=$1&productId=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.+\.([0-9]+)/.+\.([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)\.htm products.php?apiType=$2&categoryId=$1&productId=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\_'"]+/[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\_'"]+.ebay-([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+).htm products_ebay.php?apiType=$1&productId=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\_'"]+/[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\_'"]+.review-([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+).htm product_rating.php?apiType=$1&productId=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\_'"]+/[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\_'"]+.discussion-([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+).htm products_discussion.php?apiType=$1&productId=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\_'"]+/[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\_'"]+.([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+).htm products.php?apiType=$1&productId=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9&\_\-\+'"]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-z]*)/?$ category.php?categoryFn=$1&t=$2&x=$3&sk=$4&so=$5&vt=$6 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9&\_\-\+'"]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/?$ category.php?categoryFn=$1&t=$2&x=$3&sk=$4&so=$5 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9&\_\-\+'"]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ category.php?categoryFn=$1&t=$2&x=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9&\_\-\+'"]+)-([A-Z0-9_]*)-([A-Z0-9_]*)-([a-z]*)/?$ category.php?categoryFn=$1&sk=$2&so=$3&vt=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9&\_\-\+'"]+)-([A-Z0-9_]*)-([A-Z0-9_]*)/?$ category.php?categoryFn=$1&sk=$2&so=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9&\_\-\+'"]+)/?$ category.php?categoryFn=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9&\_\-\+'"]+).([0-9]+).htm $1.$2 [L,NC,R=302]
RewriteRule ^.+\.([0-9]+)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.+\.([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1&t=$2&x=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.+\.([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1&t=$2&x=$3&sk=$4&so=$5 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.+\.([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-z]*)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1&t=$2&x=$3&sk=$4&so=$5&vt=$6 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.+\.([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1&sk=$2&so=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.+\.([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-z]*)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1&sk=$2&so=$3&vt=$4 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*_([0-9]*)/[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*_ebay-([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*).htm products_ebay.php?apiType=$2&categoryId=$1&productId=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*_([0-9]*)/[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*_review-([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*).htm product_rating.php?apiType=$2&categoryId=$1&productId=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*_([0-9]*)/[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*_discussion-([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*).htm products_discussion.php?apiType=$2&categoryId=$1&productId=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*_([0-9]*)/[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.\_'"]*_([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*).htm products.php?apiType=$2&categoryId=$1&productId=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.'"]*)_([0-9]*)/?$ $1_$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.'"]*_([0-9]*)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.'"]*_([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1&t=$2&x=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.'"]*_([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1&t=$2&x=$3&sk=$4&so=$5 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.'"]*_([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-z]*)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1&t=$2&x=$3&sk=$4&so=$5&vt=$6 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.'"]*_([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1&sk=$2&so=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\+\.'"]*_([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)-([a-z]*)/?$ category.php?categoryId=$1&sk=$2&so=$3&vt=$4 [L,NC]
```

Thank for your help

Comment: Who codes such an insane configuration file?

Comment: ho this related  to mysql ???